# If my repo IS my Jekyll site, does gh-pages still need to be an orphan?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

There are many suggestions that when you start a gh-pages branch, to start the branch as an orphan and remove the contents from git.

For example, here: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-for-the-orphans and on the official github: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/

However, would this apply if my master branch *is* my gh-pages branch? That is to say, my entire repo was created to be a Jekyll site. My assumption is that gh-pages branch and the master branch should be identical.

**In the case where the repo is created solely as a Jekyll site, what is the best way to create and maintian the gh-pages branch for a project site?** I've had troubles in the past keeping the master branch and gh-pages branches identical. One solution I've been suggested to delete the master branch and have only the gh-pages branch, is this considered bad or good practice and why?

I've also seen this suggestion of nesting repos: https://gist.github.com/chrisjacob/833223 However, it seems like I really do not need a master and a gh-pages, since my repo is only gh-pages.

However, I may also have a basic misunderstanding of this since I started using Jekyll a few days ago, please let me know if it is not correct that gh-pages would be the same as master branch for a Jekyll only project, and why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

master branch is eventually used for :

- hosting a user/organisation site (`http://github.com/username/username.github.io`)
- host your Jelyll code if you use a deploying strategy like with [octopress](http://octopress.org/) (code in master, generated pages in gh-pages), mainly when you need to run plugins locally.

If you simply hosts a project site (`http://github.com/username/projectName`) that doesn't needs special plugins, you can safely delete `master` branch and use `gh-pages` as you main branch.

You can then make a new branch locally for testing purpose, then merge it in gh-pages before pushing to github.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the master branch is also used in deploying strategies like Octopress, I did end up needing my master branch when I used a Jekyll plug-in that GitHub pages did not support.

Answer (score 1):

The master branch is not special in any way other than being automatically created when you create a new repo. It can be safely ignored or even deleted if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete it, that's what I do for the majority of my Jekyll sites as it means I don't push to the wrong branch!

In your repo settings just set gh-pages as the default branch and then you can safely delete Master.